# Visual Studio Code doesn't "Find all references" in #define and macros

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code doesn't see references in #defines or macros, but Visual Studio does.
Is there a setting that I don't see, that enables this?

[image: Visual Studio Code screenshot]

[EDIT]
To show that Visual Studio (IDE) does resolve the #define reference, I took another screenshot.

[image: Visual Studio IDE screenshot]

Comment: Visual Studio the IDE has been around a lot longer and is, not surprisingly, better at deducing these things because it has an integrated compiler.

Comment: @tadman The C language has been around even longer though... Shouldn't come as a big surprise to the IDE developer that something called `#define` exists. Any half-decent IDE out there got the possibility to list all visible #defines in a file or translation unit.

Comment: @Lundin Nothing wrong with that, but Visual Studio Code is not an IDE, its an Editor, powerful, yes, but still an Editor.

Comment: @ErdalKüçük If it can do source code formatting then it should be able to list #defines.

Comment: @Lundin Nothing wrong with what you say, i think i am more forgiving? And it does do it, if proper configured and not 'tired'.

Comment: @ErdalKüçük I haven't used this one so I have no idea what it can or can't do. I just noted that even the worst IDEs out there are capable of doing this.

Comment: @Lundin Netbeans! More than one decade i was loyal to that IDE, but in the end it disappointed me and now i am pretty happy with Visual Studio Code. Although i miss sometimes a 'real' IDE. But once you 'manually' edited your config and makefiles, the rest is business as usual.

Comment: @Lundin You're more than welcome to try and extend the Visual Studio Code `#define` detection routines, it's open source.

Comment: @tadman Why would I spend by free time, contributing for free, to something named Visual Studio? I'd much rather go and pick up garbage from the streets for free - then at least I'd be doing something useful.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio Code (especially the C/C++ Extension) does a good job. Sometimes a reference cannot be resolved, in that case a restart or clearing/resetting the intellisense cache helps. But it could be also a configuration error.

In, File -> Preferences -> Settings

- in the field 'Search settings', type include. Control every entry found.

Or

[CTRL] + [SHIFT] + P

- C/C++: Rescan Workspace
- C/C++: Reset IntelliSense Database

**Addendum**

I realized it a little too late but like i mentioned it in my comment below, you have a misconception.

Analog to your problem:

```
char *FOO = "bar";
int bar = 1;
```

I don't think you expect the string literal `"bar"` to be a reference to the variable `int bar`?

Well, in your case `#define FOO bar`, `bar` is just a literal and has no relation to the variable `bar` in your main function.

I previously thought, that you have defined `bar` somewhere else and Visual Studio Code couldn't resolve it, but that's not the case.

Comment: It's the same on multiple computers, and I just did a fresh install, so I doubt it's a cache problem.
I checked what seemed relevant on the "include" search, but no luck.

Comment: Wait, now i realized it. Where is `bar` defined? Should that be a reference to `bar` in your `main` function? Well in the case `#define FOO bar` `bar` is just a 'literal' and not a reference to anything. Would it have been a constant (defined before like `#define bar 1` then Code would see and report it as 1 (as a reference to bar expanded to 1).

Comment: I've added some more info to my answer, hope it helps.

Comment: Whether it should see it as a reference or not, is a different discussion. I gave simple example, but I'm working on code that uses macros which reference variables in nested structures. So if I'm looking for all the references in a big project with multiple files, I would like to find them in macros also.

In either case, VS IDE does this correctly, as can be seen in the added screenshot. I assume that VS Code should be able to do the same.

Comment: I see. I apologize, i've never worked with Visual Studio before and i didn't know about that functionality. I use Code extensively for a few years now (on linux) and that sort of problem is solved by me with [CTRL] + [SHIFT] + F (find in files). Regex for more complex/problematic patterns. Not the ideal solution, error-prone and tedious, but that seems to be one of the differences between a fully fledged IDE and an Editor.